# Run-Time Error 287 when retrieving Outlook email properties from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am facing a "Run-time error 287" when accessing Outlook emails via Excel VBA. However, I'm getting this message only when run the script in Office 2013, with an Exchange account assigned to my Outllok client. When running in Office 2019, with my personal Outlook.com email address assigned to the client, it runs fine, doing what is expected to be done.

```
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim olFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("CV")
Set rng = Range("table1")
i = 1

For Each olMailItem In olFolder.Items
    rng.Cells(i, 1).value = olMailItem.ReceivedTime   'Success
    rng.Cells(i, 2).value = olMailItem.subject        'Success
    rng.Cells(i, 3).value = olMailItem.Sender         'Throw error 287
    rng.Cells(i, 3).value = olMailItem.SenderName     'Throw error 287
    rng.Cells(i, 4).value = Left(olMailItem.Body, 20) 'Throw error 287
    i = i + 1
Next olMailItem

Set olFolder = Nothing
Set olNamespace = Nothing
Set olApp = Nothing

MsgBox (i - 1) & " emails retrieved."
```

I have already checked on the libraries references, but their exactly the same in both scenarios I tested.

[image]

Therefore, I'm afraid it's something related to the Exchange account or even the Office version, but both hypotheses are still strange, since I can still access some of the `MailItem` properties.

Does anyone has any idea what it could be?

Comment: Have you tried late-binding the Outlook types? i.e. remove the referenced Outlook type library from references, comment-out the `As Outlook.*` declarations and replace them with `As Object`, and using `CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`instead of `New` to create the app instance?

Comment: Note that Office 2019 and Office 2013 should have different version numbers in the referenced library. "Microsoft Outlook **15.0** Object Library" is Office 2013 so if you use the 2019 the number in the referenced library should be higher (17.0 I think?).

Comment: Yes, @MathieuGuindon. I've tried and got the same message! :(

Comment: Yes, @Pᴇʜ. I'm aware of this. I got the respective library selected for each version.

Comment: That sounds like a security block. Do you have an up-to-date AV app on that machine?

Comment: Do you have permissions via Exchange to send emails on the behalf of other users?

Comment: Try to change `olMailItem` to an `Object` or set it to `olFolder.Items` before retrieving the object, you will get an error if the object is not mail item- also sender or sender name will get you the display name, to get the email address use `SenderEmailAddress`